# How to add a URL link using storyboard

Tags: xcode

I have created via Storyboard, a Navigation Controller connected to a Table View Controller where each table cell is linked to a different View Controller.  One one of these View Controller I would like to put a URL, can I do this in Storyboard ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to click on one table cell so it takes you to a website directly outside of your app ? or to a web view inside your app ?

Since you're asking about a way to do this using Storyboard, I suggest putting a **WebView** inside your View Controller.

Comment: I would click on a cell which brings me to a view and on that view I would like to have some text and a url ? I have now put a WebView onto that Controller View.  Where do I go from there?  My app has the two delegate files and the storyboard only. Thanks.

Comment: Eh Cookiki you put me on the right track and I was able to do it.  Working from storyboard I put a webview onto that window.  I then created a second view controller - I put the necessary code into the .h and .m - I change that window class to be SecondViewController class and then connected from SecondViewController to webview and it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh ! sorry I didnt see your previous comment, and you're welcome ! If you want anything more, tell me :)